# HTML elements inside template of a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular js and exploring custom directives. I have created a directive and have named it `datatable`. Below is the code:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).directive('datatable', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            friends: '='
        },
        template : 'Hey{{friends[0].firstName}} : {{friends[0].lastName}}',
        controller :function($scope)
        {
            $scope.friends =[{"firstName" : "ABC", "lastName" : "XYZ"}];
        }
    }
});
```

This code is working fine, but when I try to loop through the friend array using `ng-repeat`, it is not printing anything. I am replacing the template as below:

```
template : '<li ng-repeat ="friend in friends"> Hey{{friend.firstName}} : {{friend.lastName}}</li>'
```

I am also wondering if I use any HTML element inside template it is not working for example:

```
template : '<h1>Hey{{friends[0].firstName}} : {{friends[0].lastName}}<h1>',
```

also did not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sure would be nice if people didn't suggest nonsense edits, and if others payed attention, and din't approve nonsense edits.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, sorry for the any inconvenience caused due to edits.

Comment: No no, you are okay. I was referring to the people that were [trashing your post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4672337).

Answer (score 0):

template should have only 1 root element, try this:

```
template : '<ul><li ng-repeat ="friend in friends"> Hey{{friend.firstName}} : {{friend.lastName}}</li></ul>'
```

Comment: I had tried this option but it did not work. Thanks.